# How can I avoid ctrl in multiple select in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, select-options

I'm starting to make a `multiselect` without any package ...

When I create a select multiple, it is necessary key `ctrl` for select multiple elements.

I hate this ...

Can I make it with a function?

```html
<template>
  <select multiple v-model="selected">
      <option v-for="item in items" v-bind:key="item.id">{{item.name}}</option>
  </select>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'SelectMultiple',
  props: {
    items: Array,
  },
  data(){
    return{
      selected: ['option1']
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: You could probably use a `@click` event and do your own sauce. Meanwhile, this a Web standard. People are used to this, this is how the Web works and everybody assumes this by default. Is it a good idea to change that because **you** hate it? Probably not for all of your users.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with `:value` instead v-model and use method on click event for selecting:

```js
Vue.component('myselect', {
  template: `
    <div>
      <select multiple :value="selected" @click="selection">
        <option v-for="item in items" :key="item.id" :selected="isSelected(item.name)">{{item.name}}</option>
      </select>
      {{selected}}
    </div>
  `,
  props: {
    items: Array,
  },
  data(){
    return{
      selected: ['option1']
    }
  },
  methods: {
    isSelected(item) {
      return this.selected.includes(item) 
    },
    selection(e) {
      const el = e.target.value;
      if(this.selected.includes(el)){
        this.selected = this.selected.filter(s => s !== el)
      } else {
        this.selected = [...this.selected, el]
      }
    }
  }
})
new Vue({
  el: "#demo",
  data(){
    return{
      items: [{id:1, name:'option1'}, {id:2, name:'option2'}, {id:3, name:'option3'}, {id:4, name:'option4'}, {id:5, name:'option5'}]
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
   <myselect :items="items"></myselect>
</div>
```

Comment: it is okay, but if I edit the "selected:" into data() in { id:1, name: "option1"} it doesn't work. I have another question why in selection function you don't code with this.selected.push(el).

Comment: I made a mistake to do selected into data(). I send a data from parent to child, I need a props